# How to display blob column with mime type "application/pdf" in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I display a PDF Document which is stored in a BLOB Column on an Oracle Apex Page?

Comment: Is it actually a PDF or is it an image that has been given the wrong mime-type? If it is a PDF then what do you expect the image to be?

Comment: It is pdf ..and i want to display that pdf as usual(that is like how we see it through adobe reader).

Answer (score 2):

In the Page Attributes you can set the Mime Type to application PDF.

[image: apex page mime type]

Then you could do something like this (As a Header Process) to actually show the PDF:

```
owa_util.mime_header('application/pdf',false);
htp.p('Content-length:'||l_length);
owa_util.http_header_close;
wpg_docload.download_file(l_pdf_blob);
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
```